# Setting Up MFA and/or best security for personal computer for RDS

Tags: multi-factor, windows-10

I am in the process of converting an older computer into a dedicated machine learning server. I want to be able to RDS into it from my current computer and ideally from anywhere. However, I do want to follow best practices and prevent other people from accessing it via including some form of MFA on Windows 10 Pro. Is there a way to do this? If so how?

When looking around online all I see are business-based solutions that are super expensive. Is there a solution that is reasonably priced for an individual playing around?

Any help and insights are super appreciated!

Comment: Personally, I only open one port to a SSH server, which I then use to tunnel traffic to whichever computer I need to access. It looks like it's easy to add 2FA to SSH using PAM if that's an option for you. Note that [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-outside-access) recommends against exposing remote desktop to the Internet, instead suggesting a VPN.

Comment: On the ML server, I would setup a VPN server (OpenVPN) with authentication done via a USB token (nitrokey or yubikey) unlocked with a password. In this tunnel, you could then use whatever insecure protocol you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with Windows 10 alone.  The RDP protocol and Windows login in general do not support MFA directly.

There are many ways to make this work by adding services in front of the machine.  The canonical solution for MFA with RDP is to use Windows Server RDS Gateway as a connection broker between the client and the session host.  RD Gateway supports many authentication methods, requiring the user to authenticate to the gateway before the gateway will broker a connection to the session host.  A common networking solution is to place a VPN and firewall into place with rules configured to only allow RDP access by VPN, and only allow VPN connections by MFA.  Adding 3rd party authentication services that support MFA and using their client software to extend the Windows login service is another option.

Perhaps easiest but unconfirmed would be Duo.  They have an RDP MFA solution and a solution free for under 10 users, however I do not use Duo and cannot confirm that the free tier of service supports their RDP MFA solution.

[OpenOTP](https://www.rcdevs.com/is-your-rdp-secured/) also provides an OTP solution available in their free tier.

To write a simplistic one yourself you would code a Windows service.  The service would run continuously changing Windows local account passwords based on a known password component and the TOTP algorithm ([TOTP: Time-Based One-Time Password Algorithm](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6238.txt)).  [FreeOTP](https://freeotp.github.io/) is one possible source to obtain an open source implementation of TOTP with a fully functional authenticator app.  There are many TOTP libraries available [here](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=TOTP%20open%20source%20library).

You may have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  You are asking for a way to do RDP with MFA.  It may be better to look more generally for a secure remote control solution.  As one alternative, in a domain based setting the Windows firewall can be configured with IPsec protection on the RDP port.  This prevents non-trusted machines from accessing RDP on the target machine, while only allowing connections from trusted machines.  [Securing RDP with IPSec](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/securing-rdp-with-ipsec/ba-p/259108)

> [...]previous post on Privileged Administrative Workstations (PAW) which is a hardened device configuration used to protect privileged credentials. In that post, I mentioned that it is possible to use IPsec to ensure an admin can only make a RDP connection to Tier 0 devices (domain controllers) from a PAW. By imposing this restriction, we limit the risk of exposing highly privileged credentials to a keyboard logger on a less trusted system such as an administrator's standard workstation. An additional benefit is that we restrict how stolen credentials can be used unless an administrator's PAW is also acquired.

Comment: "To write a simplistic one yourself..." This is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Depends on the skills of the developer.  In particular using an open source TOTP library removes most of the risk of defects in the TOTP implementation.  There are many commercial password rotators, including one targeting this exact solution.  I planned to mention it by name, but at the moment I can no longer locate the vendor site.
That said, I'd personally use Azure Virtual Desktop for this solution but that does not fit the OPs requirement.

Comment: No, it's definitely a bad idea.

Comment: Care to elaborate why?  I may be biased, as I work with highly skilled professional developers who could easily do this, and highly skilled enterprise administrators running solutions like this.  I recommend "business-based solutions that are super expensive" most days of the week to my clients, but for someone like OP avoiding that path it's certainly doable if they have the correct skills.  OP states "Can be complex in nature and require custom coding" so without further background I have to let OP decide if they have the skill for this.  It's a legitimate option given the requirements.

Comment: What do you think about NordVPN's solution? To me it sounds like the same as what you are proposing above for pretty cheap. Basically acquire a dedicated IP which can only be accessed through your account, enable MFA for your account, then only open the network port to the dedicated IP address. I also like the comment of having the password be controlled by the USB key. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, after RD Gateway I'd say VPN is the most common solution.  By securing the machine behind a firewall and allowing only MFA traffic into the firewall you get a reasonable solution.  Any VPN with MFA will do, so NordVPN would work for this.  Key things to consider... make sure when the VPN is down the RDP connection remains secure, and watch for split-tunneling where only some traffic goes over the VPN.

Answer (score 2):

Whereas for Linux this kind of security practice can be easily implemented with `knockd`, this topic appears to be a rather not that touched domain in the Windows world.

It's called Port Knocking. It's usually run by a "closed down" server, where all the ports are closed, but if in a specified sequence the ports get knocked - that is pinged - the required port opens granting access thru let's say SSH or RDP.

My research has led to some PoC (Proof of Concepts), one of which is actually written in Pascal. Check it out here on GitHub: https://github.com/vigisoft/rdp-port-knocking
The code in question appears to be not complete and would require some reviewing.

Another example of port knocking is this website I found online and it also gives the source code: https://gregsowell.com/?p=2020
For archival reasons I'll post the code below:

```
#Region ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#AutoIt3Wrapper_outfile=portknock.exe
#EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <ComboConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GUIListBox.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <file.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
FileInstall("C:\Documents and Settings\greg\Desktop\autoit\portknock\TCP.exe", @ScriptDir & "\TCP.exe",0)
;knock it like it's hot
$g_IP = ""
$g_port = ""
$ListLocation = 1
 
;check config file
if not FileExists(@ScriptDir & "\config.txt") Then
    ;create it with dummy info
    $file = FileOpen(@ScriptDir & "\config.txt", 1)
    If $file = -1 Then
        MsgBox(0, "Error", "Unable to open file.")
        Exit
    EndIf
 
    FileWriteLine($file, "Description;IPAddress;UDP;Port;GregRocks")
 
    FileClose($file)
 
EndIf
 
ReadConfig ()
 
; Start The  Services
;==============================================
TCPStartUp()
UDPStartup()
 
;###########################################
 
#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=C:\Documents and Settings\greg\Desktop\autoit\portknock\Form1.kxf
$Form1_1 = GUICreate("GregSowell.com Port Knock", 441, 434, 192, 114)
$List1 = GUICtrlCreateList("", 24, 16, 393, 201)
$CBO1 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("None", 33, 280, 65, 25)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "TCP|UDP")
$In1Port = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 121, 280, 105, 21)
$In1Text = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 233, 280, 177, 21)
$Label1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("1", 9, 280, 10, 17)
$BTNKnock = GUICtrlCreateButton("Knock", 96, 400, 73, 25, $WS_GROUP)
$BTNAdd = GUICtrlCreateButton("Add/Update", 182, 400, 73, 25, $WS_GROUP)
$BTNDelete = GUICtrlCreateButton("Delete", 272, 400, 73, 25, $WS_GROUP)
$InIP = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 40, 234, 161, 21)
$Label2 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("IP", 8, 234, 14, 17)
$Label3 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Type", 44, 259, 28, 17)
$Label4 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Port", 124, 259, 23, 17)
$Label5 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Text", 238, 259, 25, 17)
$CBO2 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("None", 33, 309, 65, 25)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "TCP|UDP")
$In2Port = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 121, 309, 105, 21)
$In2Text = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 233, 309, 177, 21)
$Label6 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("2", 9, 309, 10, 17)
$CBO3 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("None", 33, 341, 65, 25)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "TCP|UDP")
$In3Port = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 121, 341, 105, 21)
$In3Text = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 233, 341, 177, 21)
$Label7 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("3", 9, 341, 10, 17)
$CBO4 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("None", 33, 367, 65, 25)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "TCP|UDP")
$In4Port = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 121, 367, 105, 21)
$In4Text = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 233, 367, 177, 21)
$Label8 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("4", 9, 367, 10, 17)
$InDesc = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 253, 234, 161, 21)
$Label9 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Desc", 221, 234, 29, 17)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###
 
PopList()
 
 
While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $BTNAdd
            ;
            $foundOne = 0
            for $y = 1 to $aConfig
                ;loop through until we find the correct line
                if StringLeft($aConfig[$y], StringInStr($aConfig[$y], ";") - 1) == GUICtrlRead($InDesc) Then
                    ; we have our match, update
                    $foundOne = $y
                EndIf
            Next
            if $foundOne == 0 Then
                ;we didn't find a match above, so write it to file, then reload listbox
                $tempNewEntry = GUICtrlRead($InDesc) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($InIP) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($CBO1) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In1Port) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In1Text)
                if GUICtrlRead($CBO2) <> "None" Then
                    ;add 2
                    $tempNewEntry = $tempNewEntry & ";" & GUICtrlRead($CBO2) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In2Port) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In2Text)
                    if GUICtrlRead($CBO3) <> "None" Then
                        ;add 3
                        $tempNewEntry = $tempNewEntry & ";" & GUICtrlRead($CBO3) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In3Port) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In3Text)
                        if GUICtrlRead($CBO4) <> "None" Then
                            ;add 4
                            $tempNewEntry = $tempNewEntry & ";" & GUICtrlRead($CBO4) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In4Port) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In4Text)
                        EndIf
                    EndIf
                EndIf
                _ArrayAdd($aConfig, $tempNewEntry)
            Else
                ;does exist, and write over line $y
                $aConfig[$foundOne] = GUICtrlRead($InDesc) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($InIP) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($CBO1) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In1Port) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In1Text)
                if GUICtrlRead($CBO2) <> "None" Then
                    ;add 2
                    $aConfig[$foundOne] = $aConfig[$foundOne] & ";" & GUICtrlRead($CBO2) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In2Port) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In2Text)
                    if GUICtrlRead($CBO3) <> "None" Then
                        ;add 3
                        $aConfig[$foundOne] = $aConfig[$foundOne] & ";" & GUICtrlRead($CBO3) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In3Port) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In3Text)
                        if GUICtrlRead($CBO4) <> "None" Then
                            ;add 4
                            $aConfig[$foundOne] = $aConfig[$foundOne] & ";" & GUICtrlRead($CBO4) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In4Port) & ";" & GUICtrlRead($In4Text)
                        EndIf
                    EndIf
                EndIf
            EndIf
            ;write array to file
            _FileWriteFromArray(@ScriptDir & "\config.txt", $aConfig,1)
            ReadConfig()
            PopList()
 
        Case $BTNDelete
            ;
            for $y = 1 to $aConfig[0]
                ;loop through until we find the correct line
                if StringLeft($aConfig[$y], StringInStr($aConfig[$y], ";") - 1) == GUICtrlRead($InDesc) Then
                    ; we have our match, update
                    _ArrayDelete($aConfig, $y)
                    _FileWriteFromArray(@ScriptDir & "\config.txt", $aConfig,1)
                    ReadConfig()
                    PopList()
                EndIf
            Next
 
        Case $BTNKnock
            ;
            $g_IP = GUICtrlRead($InIP)
            $g_port = GUICtrlRead($In1Port)
            $g_text = ""
            $g_text = GUICtrlRead($In1Text)
            if GUICtrlRead($CBO1) == "TCP" Then
                TCPKnock()
            Else
                UDPKnock()
            EndIf
            sleep(300)
            if GUICtrlRead($CBO2) <> "None" Then
                $g_port = GUICtrlRead($In2Port)
                $g_text = ""
                $g_text = GUICtrlRead($In2Text)
            EndIf
            if GUICtrlRead($CBO2) == "TCP" Then
                TCPKnock()
            Elseif GUICtrlRead($CBO2) == "UDP" Then
                UDPKnock()
            EndIf
            sleep(300)
            if GUICtrlRead($CBO3) <> "None" Then
                $g_port = GUICtrlRead($In3Port)
                $g_text = ""
                $g_text = GUICtrlRead($In3Text)
            EndIf
            if GUICtrlRead($CBO3) == "TCP" Then
                TCPKnock()
            Elseif GUICtrlRead($CBO3) == "UDP" Then
                UDPKnock()
            EndIf
            sleep(300)
            if GUICtrlRead($CBO4) <> "None" Then
                $g_port = GUICtrlRead($In4Port)
                $g_text = ""
                $g_text = GUICtrlRead($In4Text)
            EndIf
            if GUICtrlRead($CBO4) == "TCP" Then
                TCPKnock()
            Elseif GUICtrlRead($CBO4) == "UDP" Then
                UDPKnock()
            EndIf
            ToolTip("knock complete")
            sleep(5000)
            ToolTip("")
 
        case $GUI_EVENT_PRIMARYUP
            ;mouse was pressed, lets check to see if they choose a new item in list
            ;check which list item is highlighted
            $tempList = GUICtrlRead($List1)
            ;see if this is new item chosen or just a click somewhere on the prog
            if $tempList <> $ListLocation and $tempList <> "" Then
                ;change, update everything
                ;set list location to the temp value
                $ListLocation = $tempList
 
                ;clear the entries
                GUICtrlSetData($InDesc,"")
                GUICtrlSetData($InIP,"")
                GUICtrlSetData($CBO1,"None")
                GUICtrlSetData($In1Port,"")
                GUICtrlSetData($In1Text,"")
                GUICtrlSetData($CBO2,"None")
                GUICtrlSetData($In2Port,"")
                GUICtrlSetData($In2Text,"")
                GUICtrlSetData($CBO3,"None")
                GUICtrlSetData($In3Port,"")
                GUICtrlSetData($In3Text,"")
                GUICtrlSetData($CBO4,"None")
                GUICtrlSetData($In4Port,"")
                GUICtrlSetData($In4Text,"")
                ;set the entries
                for $y = 1 to $aConfig[0]
                    ;loop through until we find the correct line
                    if StringLeft($aConfig[$y], StringInStr($aConfig[$y], ";") - 1) == $ListLocation Then
                        ; we have our match
                        $ConfigLine = $aConfig[$y]
                    EndIf
                Next
                ;fill in all the boxes
                GUICtrlSetData($InDesc, $ListLocation)
                GUICtrlSetData($InIP, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";") + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,2) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";") - 1))
                GUICtrlSetData($CBO1, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,2) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,3) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,2) - 1))
                GUICtrlSetData($In1Port, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,3) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,4) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,3) - 1))
                GUICtrlSetData($In1Text, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,4) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,5) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,4) - 1))
                $tempstring = StringReplace($ConfigLine, ";", ";")
                $tempCount = @extended
                if $tempCount > 4 Then
                    ;we have a second set
                    GUICtrlSetData($CBO2,  StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,5) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,6) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,5) - 1))
                    GUICtrlSetData($In2Port, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,6) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,7) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,6) - 1))
                    GUICtrlSetData($In2Text, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,7) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,8) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,7) - 1))
                EndIf
                if $tempCount > 7 Then
                    ;we have a third set
                    GUICtrlSetData($CBO3, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,8) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,9) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,8) - 1))
                    GUICtrlSetData($In3Port, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,9) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,10) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,9) - 1))
                    GUICtrlSetData($In3Text, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,10) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,11) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,10) - 1))
                EndIf
                if $tempCount > 10 Then
                    ;we have a fourth set
                    GUICtrlSetData($CBO4, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,11) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,12) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,11) - 1))
                    GUICtrlSetData($In4Port, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,12) + 1, StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,13) - StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,12) - 1))
                    GUICtrlSetData($In4Text, StringMid($ConfigLine,StringInStr($ConfigLine,";",0,4) + 1))
                EndIf
 
            EndIf
 
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            TCPShutdown()
            UDPShutdown()
            Exit
 
    EndSwitch
WEnd
;###########################################
 
Func PopList ()
    ;populate list box
    GUICtrlSetData($List1, "")
    for $x = 1 to $aConfig[0]
        GUICtrlSetData($List1, StringLeft($aConfig[$x], StringInStr($aConfig[$x], ";") - 1))
    Next
EndFunc
 
Func ReadConfig ()
    Global $aConfig
    If Not _FileReadToArray(@ScriptDir & "\config.txt",$aConfig) Then
        MsgBox(4096,"Error", " Error reading log to Array     error:" & @error)
        Exit
    EndIf
EndFunc
 
;knock functions
Func TCPKnock ()
    ToolTip("knocking " & $g_IP & " " & $g_port)
    run("""" & @ScriptDir & "\TCP.exe"" " & $g_IP & " " & $g_port)
    ToolTip("")
EndFunc
 
Func UDPKnock ()
    ToolTip("knocking " & $g_IP & " " & $g_port)
    $socket = UDPOpen($g_IP, $g_port)
    $status = UDPSend($socket, $g_text)
    UDPCloseSocket($socket)
    ToolTip("")
EndFunc
```

```
#NoTrayIcon
;include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
 
Opt('MustDeclareVars', 1)
; Set Some reusable info
   ;--------------------------
Local $ConnectedSocket, $szData
; Set $szIPADDRESS to wherever the SERVER is. We will change a PC name into an IP Address
;   Local $szServerPC = @ComputerName
;   Local $szIPADDRESS = TCPNameToIP($szServerPC)
Local $szIPADDRESS = $CmdLine[1]
Local $nPORT = $CmdLine[2]
 
; Start The TCP Services
;==============================================
TCPStartup()
 
; Initialize a variable to represent a connection
;==============================================
$ConnectedSocket = -1
 
;Attempt to connect to SERVER at its IP and PORT 33891
;=======================================================
$ConnectedSocket = TCPConnect($szIPADDRESS, $nPORT)
TCPCloseSocket($ConnectedSocket)
```

You could also limit/temporary ban RDP attempts on an open port.

Another thing you could do is (or expand upon) would be to automatically ban bruteforce attempts on an RDP port, but for this you would require to have a port open, which I *wouldn't* recommend. If you're still interested or generally want to be informed for research purposes or similar there is great software like this piece of software for example: https://github.com/devnulli/EvlWatcher

Another rather good topic is what is in Linux known as `PAMs` (Plugggable Authentication Modules). Please do not confuse with Windows own Privileged Access Management in the AD. These modules can for example include Google Authentication and further well known MFA methods like YubiKey and so on. This is actually an authentication method you could easily add onto existing security systems.

Lucky for you such a thing actually exists for Windows as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10611249/11300553

Apparently this means that you would seem to require to have Kerberos installed in the system for this additional authentication to work.

I would personally would go with Port Knocking if the security demands are high or if I have low demands just keep one port open and use `EvlWatcher` or similar software. I would most definitely try to build up on that with the Linux PAMs equivalent described above.

P.S. I've had a thought and after the inspiration from one Unix & Linux StackExchange Post you could try to have the filesystem encrypted in one country and have the private key for it in another country using a Cloud provider (which you of course will have to trust then) and then seal off the one device from the internet and keep a link between these two devices. Apparently I didn't manage to find anything equivalent for Windows in this topic, just a shower thought.
You could also use a friend's device of course instead of a cloud provider.

Comment: This is a great answer with a ton of very interesting techniques I have never heard of previously. Thanks you!

Comment: If you need help combining this or need more research from my side just let me know ^^